# Google Order Management Problem: Orders dont appear ing google order management

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I use Google In App Billling for selling game coins. users are buying game credits by paying, but these orders do not appear in google developer console's order management.
That means I can't get the payment. What do you think about it? 
Please help me...

Comment: Same problem. I got even order id, purchase token but there is nothing on Order Management panel. It seems like frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Play orders are frozen here too. I have sent an email using the help link in the Play console. Hopefully transactions are not lost.